# How can i detect that user has pressed enter key (in java) And what, if i want to use enter key in the condition of a loop?

Tags: java

please help me!

M new to java. I want that a specific line of my code must be executed just after the enter button has been pressed. Like: int x= in.nextInt(); then a value is stored in x after pressing enter.

now i want to use such mechanism in a loop.means; perform this statement if Enter button has pressed else do another statement.

if(!Enter key pressed)

### {

---

}
else if(space has been pressed)

### {

---

}
now tell me what kind of code should i write in java?

i don't want to use listeners.

so suggest me what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Simply read a line of input. If you're reading from user input:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input = null;
try {
     input = br.readLine();
     //this code will be executed after user pressed enter
} catch (IOException e) {
     //handle exception
}
```

Likewise, if you're reading from a file, simply change System.in to your file (opened with a File object):

```
File file = new File(path);    
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileReader(file)));
```

If you want to distinguish between input characters (such as enter or space), read it character by character (instead of complete line) - simply use read() instead of readLine() - and ask what the value of the character is:

```
char c = (char)br.read();
if (c == ' ') {
   // this is a space
} else if (c == '\n') {
   // this is a new line (Enter)
}
```

Notice that '\n' will work for most operating systems, as Linux only uses it to mark a new line and Windows uses '\r\n'. If you want to support iOS as well, you may ask if the character is '\r' (but has no '\n' following it)